# In ww.es does a Reviver revive an avatar or a player

Tags: werewolv.es

It's basically the title. I've been wondering that for a while since it isn't really clear at this moment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little more? Is this in relation to identity swaps also happening in the same night?

Comment: It is indeed in relation to Identity swaps happening that same night.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment clarification, I'll assume this question to be "if a Reviver targets a dead player, Alice and a Djinn swaps the avatars of players Alice and Bob on the same night, who is revived?" The answer is player Alice is revived, but they will have Bob's avatar.

To elaborate - in 99% of cases in werewolv.es actions affect the *player* that was hidden behind the avatar at the start of the night not where the *avatar* eventually winds up.

```
| Player | Avatar          |
|--------|-----------------|
| Alice  | Black Widow     |
| Bob    | Captain America |
```

- a Reviver targets the Black Widow avatar, which resolves to player Alice, this queues a "revive Alice" action
- a Djinn targets the Black Widow and Captain America avatars, resolving to Alice and Bob, this queues a "swap the avatars of Alice and Bob" action

Identity swaps are resolved before revives and kills a reported, so everyone will see the avatar of Captain America being resurrected, but the player controlling it will now be Alice